# Looking for an algorithm for sorting different types of objects

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two different types of objects, both of which have an integer which holds their priority. In another class I want to go through each object in an order that depends on those priorities, objects with higher priorities go before ones with lower priorities.

Now my issue is that the objects are of two different types. This makes it harder for me to sort them.

The class that cycles has two `ArrayLists`, one which holds objects of one type, the other holds objects of the other type.

Here is what I've thought of so far:

1. Create an `ArrayList` of Booleans and two `ArrayLists` of Integers.
2. Loop through the list of the first object type, adding a True Boolean to the Boolean list and the index in the object list to the Integer list, and the priority to the second Integer list.
3. Now loop through the list of the second type of object, adding a False boolean to the boolean list and the index in the second list to the Integer list, and the priority to the other integer list.
4. Now I would go through the `ArrayList` of priorities and sort so higher numbers come first. At the same time I would also sort the other two lists in the same way that I'm sorting the priority list.

In a scenario with few objects in each list, like four in each, this is what the Boolean list and the Integer list could look like:

> Booleans: True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False
>
> Index Integers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> Priority Integers: 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1

After sorting by priority, it would look like this:

> Booleans: False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False
>
> Index Integers: 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3
>
> Priority Integers: 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Now the class that cycles knows who goes first and what type of object it is.

This will work, but it is ugly and there has to be a quicker way to do this, or at the very least an easier way. Or perhaps do what I was planning but more efficiently. I am open to ideas of an entirely different algorithm or an adjustment to the algorithm I described.

Comment: Call [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)(s).

Comment: Have you tried using a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a custom comparator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your two classes are `Class1` and `Class2`. You should make them implement an interface like:

```
public interface Priorizable
{
   int getPriority();
}
```

Then, create a `Comparator` for that `interface`:

```
public class PriorityComparator implement Comparator<Priorizable>
{
  public int compare(final Priorizable p1, final Priorizable p2)
  {
      return Integer.compare(p1.getPriority(), p2.getPriority())
  }
}
```

Put all your objects from `Class1` and `Class2` in a single list and sort:

```
Collections.sort(listOfPriorizable, new PriorityComparator());
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having two lists, use one list that associates each key (priority) and value (index) in an object.

```
public class Set extends Comparable<Set>{
    public Integer key;
    public Integer value;
    public Set(Integer key, Integer value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Set s){
        return key.compareTo(s.key)
    }
}
```

Since these Set objects are comparable to other Set objects, you can simply add them all to a single ArrayList and then call collections.sort() on that list.

Or you can take a look a priority queue.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html
Although that may be over thinking things for your simple case.

Comment: This indeed appears best among all the answers! An upvote from your rival respondent!

Answer (score 2):

If the two types of objects belong to classes that have a common super-class, you can store them in a single Collection of that super-class, and sort that Collection.

If not, you can still define an interface that both classes implement, such as `Priorityable` (since both have priority). Then you can store them in a Collection of that interface and sort the Collection by priority.

If it's essential that both types of objects remain in separate lists, sort each list separately based on the priority. Then define an Iterator that iterates over those lists in order. It is initialized by setting two indices (one for each list) to zero. The `next()` method would compare the priority of the next object in both lists to determine which should be returned next.

Comment: he/she doesn't even need a common super class, he can have an interface they both implement

Comment: @AmirAfghani That's what I said in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort()` will help you to compare values of different kinds of objects with each collection implementing `java.util.Comparator` would be a good possible option! But,do make sure that they can be compared using custom `compare()` implementations by all the collections(in your case ArrayList) as hinted by `Elliott Frisch`!

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the definition of the two different objects that you have collections of, you can create an interface that defines the "priority" integer and have both object implement that interface. Once you have done that, you should probably just put them all into a single ordered collection that is ordered by the "priority" value.

Answer (score 1):

In Java everything is an `Object`. So the commonality is `Ojbect`. The other commonality is the Integer priority, which is what needs to be sorted. So even if your items are Cats and Dogs with no Animal parent class, you can sort them simply demanding on whether you add elements often or read elements often:

- if you add elements often then use a priority queue of arrays `{Integer, Object}
- if you read elements often, then just use 2D array of `Object[]=new Object[n][2]`

In your priority queue of {Object, Object} where the first Object is Integer and the second is Cat or Dog, you sort on Integer.

Or in your n-by-2 array `myObjects` where `myObjects[x][0]` are Integers you sort your objects using any elementary algorithm as http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/sorting/selectionsort

THEN is you only needed to sort once in a while, you partition the list into two sorted lists: one for Cats and one for Dogs. Otherwise, just keep the queue and walk it when needed. Also an alternative to using a queue is a BST as http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bst/add and walk in-order when you need a Cat or a Dog. If you like this answer and you want further help, let me know.